# Zero divisors of the formal power series ring $A[[x]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, formal-power-series

In class we started studying the formal power series ring $A[[x]]$ of a ring $A$ and I've been all day trying to find how the zero divisors of this formal power series ring $A[[x]]$ should be, if $A$ is a commutative ring with unity.

> I suspect the answer is similar to the case of the polynomial ring $A[x]$: We have that $f\in A[x]$ is a zero divisor if and only if there exists $c\in A$, $c\neq 0$ such as $cf = 0$.

However I haven't been able to prove if this works to $A[[x]]$ as well, since the demonstration in the case of $A[x]$ involves applying induction of the degree of the polynomial.

I could really use some help or lead with this, either with the demonstration or to tell me I'm wrong in my suspicions and how the zero divisors should actually be.

Thanks fo reading me so far, and have a nice day wherever you are!

Comment: If $f$ has a multiplicative inverse then it can't be a divisor of zero. Construct the multiplicative inverse, if it exists. For $f$ which are divisible by powers of $x$, divide out by that power of $x$ first.

Comment: Just googling "zero divisor power series" returns as the first hit (for me) the paper https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-027-03/S0002-9939-1971-0271100-6/S0002-9939-1971-0271100-6.pdf and the abstract will tell you something useful.

Comment: I vaguely remember seeing a similar question relatively recently but I can't find it.  In any case, I don't think there is any simple description of the zero divisors in general, and in particular your guess is wrong.  (There is a counterexample at the end of the paper KCd linked.)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, been on finals! Yeah, I need to work on that paper. Thanks!